# Running the same junit test case using selenium webdriver in multiple instances of the same browser (load testing)

Tags: selenium, junit, testng, selenium-grid

I'm trying to simulate a firefox load testing situation. I want my to test how 10 simultaneous logins would play out on my system. I already have a connected selenium grid hub and 10 open nodes.

So far, I know I can write the test case and run it 10 times which isn't what I need because it isn't automated. I also know that I can use invocation count on the test to make it run as many times as i want but this only works on the same browser node.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to automatically distribute the same test case to multiple instances of the same driver profile?

i.e. Run a login case test times on the same firefox profile open in 10 different nodes in parallel.

Gracias!

P.S. I built my tests using testNG if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Basically selenium and testNG is not for such requiurement. You should use some dedicated tool for that like jmeter.

However you can run n methods parrallel let say if you want to login with 10 dif user in 10 thread/browser you can create test data driven and configure to run method in parrallel. Make sure you are providing proper value of parrallel thread count.

Answer (score 0):

How about combining threadpoolsize with invocationcount. - http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-running

Grid would take care to distribute on the 10 nodes.

Answer (score 0):

use headless browser  like [GHOST](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver) and then invoke multiple threads as ghost has no UI so it would work in your case